# Zeus + Vagrant remove .zeus.sock and try again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, zeus

Vagrant with Ubuntu, Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0.1, Zeus 0.13.3.rc2

I'm going to the /vagrant directory then

```
export ZEUSSOCK=/tmp/zeus.sock
zeus start
Starting Zeus server
Unable to accept socket connection.
```

It looks like Zeus is already running. If not, remove .zeus.sock and try again.

**I cannot find a .zeus.sock file anywhere.**

```
zeus d
Can't connect to master. Run zeus start first.
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: How are you looking for the `.zeus.sock` file?

Comment: Have you run `ls -la` in the project folder? What happens if you run `rm .zeus.sock`?

Comment: it's not there, it's not in the project folder, it's not in the /tmp folder :/

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved the issue for myself in a different fashion.

I was getting the `remove .zeus.sock and try again` error because I inadvertently was trying to start zeus in my home directory rather than the root of a rails project.

A simple `cd` fixed my issue, but I wasted a bunch time searching for a non-existent `.zeus.sock` before I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to 'zeus', ">= 0.13.4.pre2" it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I got working if installed the gem 0.13.4.pre2 in my Ubuntu terminal:

```
/opt/ruby/bin/gem install zeus -v 0.13.4.pre2
```

After that I can use something as:

```
zeus start
```

And all zeus commands will be working fine.